# Dynamic html elements in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js

How is it possible to add elements dynamically to the content? Example below:

```
<template>
    {{{ message | hashTags }}}
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        ...

        filters: {
            hashTags: function(value) {
                // Replace hash tags with links
                return value.replace(/#(\S*)/g, '<a v-on:click="someAction()">#$1</a>')
            }
        }
    }
</script>
```

Problem is that if I press the link no action will fire. Vue do not see new elements.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

**Update:**
Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48813523/392102), you can do a similar dynamic-template component in Vue 2. You can actually set up the component spec in the `computed` section and bind it using [`:is`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Dynamic-Components)

```js
var v = new Vue({
  el: '#vue',
  data: {
    message: 'hi #linky'
  },
  computed: {
    dynamicComponent: function() {
      return {
        template: `<div>${this.hashTags(this.message)}</div>`,
        methods: {
          someAction() {
            console.log("Action!");
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    hashTags: function(value) {
      // Replace hash tags with links
      return value.replace(/#(\S*)/g, '<a v-on:click="someAction">#$1</a>')
    }
  }
});

setTimeout(() => {
  v.message = 'another #thing';
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/vue@latest/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="vue">
  <component :is="dynamicComponent" />
</div>
```

Vue bindings don't happen on interpolated HTML. You need something Vue sees as a template, like [a partial](http://vuejs.org/api/#partial). However, Vue only applies bindings to a partial once; you can't go back and change the template text and have it re-bind. So each time the template text changes, you have to create a new partial.

There is a `<partial>` tag/element you can put in your HTML, and it accepts a variable name, so the procedure is:

- the template HTML changes
- register new partial name for the new template HTML
- update name variable so the new partial is rendered

It's a little bit horrible to register something new every time there's a change, so it would be preferable to use a component with a more structured template if possible, but if you really need completely dynamic HTML with bindings, it works.

The example below starts out with one message, link-ified as per your filter, and after two seconds, changes `message`.

You can just use `message` as the name of the partial for registering, but you need a computed that returns that name after doing the registering, otherwise it would try to render before the name was registered.

```js
var v = new Vue({
  el: 'body',
  data: {
    message: 'hi #linky'
  },
  computed: {
    partialName: function() {
      Vue.partial(this.message, this.hashTags(this.message));
      return this.message;
    }
  },
  methods: {
    someAction: function() {
      console.log('Action!');
    },
    hashTags: function(value) {
      // Replace hash tags with links
      return value.replace(/#(\S*)/g, '<a v-on:click="someAction()">#$1</a>')
    }
  }
});

setTimeout(() => {
  v.$set('message', 'another #thing');
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.26/vue.min.js"></script>
<partial :name="partialName"></partial>
```

Comment: I want to say you big thanks, I have searched about this 3 days .., asked in gitter and all have said that it is not possible, but you made it. But you have said that it is not a very good solution, my goal is to replace `#hashtags`, `@mentions` with the links maybe there are any better solution? Of course I can prepare it on the backend side, but it looks better, when all logic is served on the one side.

Comment: At some point since your post... [Partials have been removed in favor of more explicit data flow between components, using props](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Vue-partial-removed)

Answer (score 13):

I just learned about `$compile`, and it seems to fit your need very nicely. A very simple directive using `$compile` avoids all the registrations.

```js
Vue.directive('dynamic', function(newValue) {
    this.el.innerHTML = newValue;
    this.vm.$compile(this.el);
});

var v = new Vue({
  el: 'body',
  data: {
    message: 'hi #linky'
  },
  computed: {
    messageAsHtml: function() {
      return this.message.replace(/#(\S*)/g, '<a v-on:click="someAction()">#$1</a>');
    }
  },
  methods: {
    someAction: function() {
      console.log('Action!');
    }
  }
});

setTimeout(() => {
  v.$set('message', 'another #thing');
}, 2000);
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/1.0.26/vue.min.js"></script>
<div v-dynamic="messageAsHtml"></div>
```

Comment: Cool stuff, thanks!  [Directives can be registered locally too](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html)

Comment: Be aware that this question was from the Vue 1 days.

Comment: @RoyJ, `compile` looks interesting. Do you have some info about performance of `compile` in such cases?

Comment: @webprogrammer I don't, but more importantly, I don't think `compile` carried over into Vue 2.

Comment: @RoyJ, `compile` still exists in vue2 https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-compile

Comment: I'm going to try this today.  Will this work with any set of nested html containing v-model and @click mappings?

Answer (score 5):

In Vue.js 2 it's easier:

```
new Vue({
    ...,
    computed: {
        inner_html() {
            return ...; // any raw html
        },
    },
    template: `<div v-html='inner_html'></div>`,
});
```

Comment: Great concept that does render the html, however none of the embedded v-model or v-bind:is or @click handlers work.

Comment: This is closer...it actually does render the html dynamically, but if it has any v-model or other vue directives, they won't get hooked up to be reactive.

Answer (score 2):

The best solution I found which works fine with custom html is looks like this, it's like you kind of create new component each times the html property changes. No actually one did this, we just use computed property for creating new component.

That is how it looks:

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#root",
  data: {
      value: '',
      name: 'root',
      htmlData: '<div><input @input="onInputProxy($event)" ' +
                            'v-model="value" ' + 
                            'v-for="i in 3" ' + 
                            ':ref="`customInput${i}`"></div>'
  },
  computed: {
    // our component is computed property which returns the dict
    htmlDataComponent () {
      return {
        template: this.htmlData, // we use htmlData as template text

        data() {
          return {
            name: 'component',
            value: ''
          }
        },
        created () {
          // value of "this" is formComponent
          console.log(this.name + ' created');
        },
        methods: {
          // proxy components method to parent method,
          // actually you done have to
          onInputProxy: this.onInput
        }
      }
    }
  },
  methods: {
    onInput ($event) {
      // while $event is proxied from dynamic formComponent
      // value of "this" is parent component
      console.log(this.name + ' onInput');

      // use refs to refer to real components value
      console.log(this.$refs.htmlDataComponent.value);
      console.log(this.$refs.htmlDataComponent.$refs.customInput1);
      console.log(this.$refs.htmlDataComponent.$refs.customInput2);
      console.log(this.$refs.htmlDataComponent.$refs.customInput3);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.1.10/vue.min.js">
</script>

<div id="root">
  <component ref="htmlDataComponent" 
             v-if="htmlData"
             :is="htmlDataComponent"></component>
</div>
```

I did not check it for memory efficiency, but it looks like works just fine.

Comment: What if the dynamic content has recursive child tags that also have v-model mapping back to the parent vue component where the component tag above is defined in?

I need to dynamically have all recursively generated content render with the v-model hooks working.  (This was something OpenLazslo did really well and I'm hoping Vue JS can do the same.)

Answer (score 1):

Since `partial` has been removed from VueJS 2 (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/migration.html#Vue-partial-removed)

A better way may be to create a component which processes its content and create appropriate DOM elements

The above component will replace hashtags by clickable links

```html
<process-text>Hi #hashtag !</process-text>
```

```js
Vue.component('process-text', {
    render: function (createElement) {
        var hashtagRegex = /(^|\W)(#[a-z\d][\w-]*)/ig
        var text = this.$slots.default[0].text
        var list = text.split(hashtagRegex)
        var children = []
        for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
            var element = list[i]
            if (element.match(hashtagRegex)) {
                children.push(createElement('a', {
                attrs: {
                    href: 'https://www.google.fr/search?q=' + element,
                    target: "_blank"
                    },
                domProps: {
                    innerHTML: element
                    }
                }))
            } else {
                children.push(element)
            }
        }
    }
    return createElement('p', {}, children)  // VueJS expects root element
})
```

Comment: Does this re-bind all children to their v-model bindings externally to the main data of the view page?  

I'm going to try this, but I wondered if anyone tried this as well.

Comment: This returns: "[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <process-text> - did you register the component correctly?  For recursive components, make sure to provide the "name" option." ...

I added a "name=" to the <process-text> tag and it worked for normal html, but not for Vue JS tags with v-model.

Comment: The issue with using "render" is it requires every child tag the hierarchy to be created with the function "createElement" passed as a param to the render method.

Answer (score 1):

Modified version of @RoyJ's answer, works in Vue.js v2.6.10

```
new Vue({
    ...,
    computed: {
        inner_html() {
            return ...; // any raw html
        },
    },
    directives: {
        dynamic: {
            bind(el, binding) {
                el.innerHTML = binding.value;
            },
            update(el, binding) {
                el.innerHTML = binding.value;
            },
        },
    },
    template: `<div v-dynamic='inner_html'></div>`,
});
```

Comment: Will this work with nested html tags that also have v-model and @click directives?  I need to experiment with this today.