# Use jquery file in vuejs to change html

Tags: jquery, vue.js

For my project, i have to change the row in a table from text to ahref in some case when the data is loading. So my idea is to use the jquery file to verify if the table head is in the condition.

Jquery file 'resources.js' :

```
 console.log("Begin ");

 $("#td.admin-content").on("load", function(event) {
    console.log("Log 1");
    const elt = event.target;
    $(elt).html("<a href='" + $(elt).text() + "'>download</a>")
 })
```

In vuejs i call jquery in mounted :

```
mounted(){
    this.modifyOnLoadData();
},

methods: {
        modifyOnLoadData: function(){
            let script = document.createElement('script');
            script.setAttribute('src', 'resources.js');
            document.head.appendChild(script);
        },
 }
```

I see the log "Begin" but not the log "Log 1", the row displays alway the text.
I try to call this method in beforeMount but it gives the same resultl.

Something wrong here? or can i do this differently, only with vuejs?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: hi 
please write long description

Comment: Generally, it's best not to use jQuery with Vue. They are 2 different, conflicting, ways of doing the same thing. The point of a reactive framework (like Vue) is to change HTML automatically based on the state of the app.

Comment: Thanks Dan, i'm a newbie in vuejs so there are a lot of thinks i have to learn. i've try with dynamic html https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39516731/dynamic-html-elements-in-vue-js but it's not work in my case.

Comment: You don't need dynamic HTML elements, this is a very simple Vue question. I would suggest reading the [guide](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/) to learn the framework.  You would use `v-if` or `v-show` for what you want, along with a variable tracking whether content is loaded or not.

Comment: In fact, i want to display the database on my site. For exemple, i want to display the row name of table A on red, change the resource of tab B to haref ... There are around twenty v-if so i
want to write it in a separate file, like we do in CSS.