# Nuxt.js dynamic component error "Either pre-compile the templates into render functions, or use the compiler-included build"

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm getting the following error in Nuxt.js:

```
[Vue warn]: You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates into render functions, or use the compiler-included build.

found in

---> <Anonymous>
       <RenderPost> at components/RenderPost.vue
         <Pages/post/Id.vue> at pages/post/_id.vue
           <Nuxt>
             <Layouts/default.vue> at layouts/default.vue
               <Root>
```

I was following the examples here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/39519105 and my `RenderPost.vue` roughly looks like this:

```html
<template>
    <client-only>
        <component :is="dynamicComponent" />
    </client-only>
</template>

<script>
export default {
    methods:
    {
        linkedView()
        {
            return `<a href="#" @click.prevent="runSomething">Click me</a>`;
        },

    },
    computed :
    {
        dynamicComponent() {
            return {
                data() { return { foo : null }},
                template : `<div>${this.linkedView()}<br>{{ foo }}</div>`,
                methods :
                {
                    runSomething()
                    {
                        this.foo = 'ran something!'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

I added the `<client-only>` because I was also getting error about server and client not matching up. Without it, I get an additional error that says:

```
[Vue warn]: The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered content. This is likely caused by incorrect HTML markup, for example nesting block-level elements inside <p>, or missing <tbody>. Bailing hydration and performing full client-side render.
```

Comment: Dynamic componenet accepts the **name** of component, not the **template** to render. You register a component, let's call it `RenderPost`. To dynamically display it through the dynamic component,  you'd use `<component is="RenderPost" />`. Additionally, you can also supply parameters using `<component is="RenderPost" v-bind="{key: value}" />`

Comment: If I'm understanding your comment, the dynamic component needs a name, I added it in the question, does not resolve the error. The linked example does not seem to have a name.

Comment: @N.B. Actually, `<component>` does support a computed component definition as the OP is doing. The error is due to the fact that string templates are used, while the build is not configured to use the full Vue build that includes the compiler.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nuxt normally includes the Vue runtime only (excludes the compiler) as an optimization that reduces the build size by ~10KB, as most users employ precompiled templates (e.g., via single file components). The Vue runtime-only build emits the warning you're observing when in-DOM or string templates are used at runtime.

Since your app requires string templates at runtime, you'll need to configure Nuxt to use the [Vue build that includes the compiler](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/installation.html#Runtime-Compiler-vs-Runtime-only):

```js
// nuxt.config.js
export default {
  build: {
    extend(config) {
      config.resolve.alias.vue = 'vue/dist/vue.common'
    }
  },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The snippet below shows how `<component :is="dynamicComponent"></component>` works.

- 2 components are registered to `Vue` (globally)
- on the click of a button, the `:is` binding is updated with one of the registered component names
- the components themselves are emitting an event back to the parent on the click of a button

```js
Vue.component('Comp1', {
  template: `
    <div>
      COMPONENT 1<br />
      <button
        @click="() => $emit('clicked', 1)"
      >
        Click 1
      </button>
    </div>
  `
})

Vue.component('Comp2', {
  template: `
    <div>
      COMPONENT 2<br />
      <button
        @click="() => $emit('clicked', 2)"
      >
        Click 2
      </button>
    </div>
  `
})

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data() {
    return {
      dynamicComponent: 'Comp1'
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleComponent() {
      if (this.dynamicComponent === 'Comp1') {
        this.dynamicComponent = 'Comp2'
      } else {
        this.dynamicComponent = 'Comp1'
      }
    },
    handleClicked(id) {
      console.log('click in comp', id)
    }
  },
  template: `
    <div>
      <button
        @click="toggleComponent"
      >
        SWITCH COMPONENT
      </button>
      <br />
      <component
        :is="dynamicComponent"
        @clicked="(id) => handleClicked(id)"
      ></component>
    </div>
  `
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```