# How to add reactive data to nested vanilla DOM elements in Vue 3?

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

How can I add reactive data to DOM elements in the runtime? I do not have access to these elements as tags in the Vue <template>, where I would normally just write *<div>{{ myReactiveData }}</div>*.

```
<template>
    <div ref="myDiv"></div>
</template>

<script>
    import { defineComponent, ref } from 'vue';
    
    export default defineComponent({    
        
        setup()
        {
            // Lets pretend this is some kind of third party vanilla JS component, not originally made for Vue
            const someComponent = document.createElement('div');
            const nestedDiv = document.createElement('div');
            someComponent.appendChild(nestedDiv);
            
            // Setup some normal Vue stuff, 'myDiv' is the root div ref
            const myDiv = ref(null)
            
            onMounted( () => {
                // Add the "Third party element" to the DOM
                myDiv.value.appendChild(someComponent);
            });
            
            // What I want to do, is to add a reactive property nested inside the vanilla js component
            const myReactiveData = ref('Initial string');
            nestedDiv.innerText = myReactiveData.value; // This doesn't work, it is not reactive at runtime
            
            setTimeout(()=>{
                myReactiveData.value = 'Hello world!'; // Never updates
            }, 1000);

            return { myDiv, myReactiveData };
        
        },
    });
</script>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39516731/2333214

Comment: From this link, I understand that I can make a dynamic component at runtime, however I don't understand how I can add it to the DOM at runtime?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the use case of `watch` or `watchEffect`. Basically what you are trying to do is to perform a side effect (imperatively updating your DOM) when some reactive data changes. You can refer to the [official documentation](https://v3.vuejs.org/guide/reactivity-computed-watchers.html#watcheffect) for how those should be used